# Updating multiple rows of a single column with dynamically generated values in mysql

Tags: mysql

In a database table I have the following columns

```
ID   CLASS        HEIGHT
R0   RECTANGLE     40px
R1   RECTANGLE     40px
S0   SQUARE        20px
R2   RECTANGLE     40px
R3   RECTANGLE     40px
```

Now if I am deleting the row with ID='R1', I want to change the ID of R2 as R1 and R3 as R2 and so on..
 If any row is deleted then I have tried :

```
 $numofRectangles // total number of rows with class='RECTANGLE'
 for($i=0;$i<$numofRectangles;$i++)
  {
   $RectId="R".$i;
    $updatequery=mysql_query("update TABLE1 set ID='$RectId' where CLASS='RECTANGLE'");
  }
```

But, this is updaing all the ID with the last iteration

Comment: I have to be a bit stackOverflowy and ask, do you really need to do that? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely normal because everytime you execute the update query it updates all the colums that has "RECTANGLE" in their class column you should use more spesific identifier in your where clause .

This should work.

```
$idnum=0;
$query=mysql_query("select ID from TABLE1 where class='RECTANGLE'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    mysql_query("update TABLE1 set ID='R$idnum' where ID='".$row["ID"]."'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working after increasing the id in each iteration

Comment: Yep sorry i forgot to add it while writing i was in a hurry at work :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need the current rectangle ID in the WHERE condition so as to not update all rectangles.

`UPDATE TABLE1 set ID='$RectId' WHERE ID='$CurrentRectId'`